# Ethereum: Error: *** Deployment Failed *** "Migrations" -- invalid sender

Tags: npm, ethereum, truffle

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on a private blockchain on ethereum network. But it gives me this error" **Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"Migrations" -- invalid sender.**"

Now I have done some reading and saw the problem is with the version of "**truffle hdwallet provider**".
This is the response that I get after installing npm inside directory which shows that hdwallet is installed but still i get this error.

[image]

Even if i install another version of hdwallet provider I get the same error as seen below:
[image]

I dont understand what am i missing here. If someone can help i will be greatfull. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was not actually the problem with **truffle hdwallet** but the **version of truffle**. Truffle 5.2.6 was giving me that error and it works fine with truffle 5.0.0.